# How to set up different azure sendgrid accounts for different environments?

Tags: email, azure, sendgrid

We are using azure for publishing our application and we are having three different web apps for dev, stage and prod.

By referring the below link

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email/

We configured the sendgrid account in azure and we are able to send email without any issue in all three environments dev, stag and prod.

**Note:** We are using same sendgrid account for dev, stage and prod.

**Issue:**

Now, for tracking and billing purpose we decided to use different sendgrid accounts for dev, stag and prod. i.e.,

Azure SendGrid account 1 - dev

Azure SendGrid account 2 - stag

Azure SendGrid account 3 - prod

But we don't know how to accomplish via azure portal and when we tried it's not allowing.

Please, suggest some steps or links to accomplish this so that we can plan out for release. Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having, at which part are you stuck? Creating the additional send grid accounts or using dev / staging to access them?

Comment: @Michael B Creating additional sendgrid account for dev, stag and prod

Comment: Forego using Azure and the portal to set up the accounts. Just create them with/in SendGrid.

Comment: Otherwise, to track the billing to each environment, create three different subscriptions in Azure (one for each environment) then create a new SendGrid account via the Marketplace and tie it to the proper subscription.

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid supports subusers, so you could have your parent account and two or three subusers depending on if you wanted to send via the parent account as well. You can [read about subusers](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/Subusers/index.html) on the SendGrid docs. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

About halfway down in the article you provided a link for you'll see:

[image]

and

[image: screenshot from article]

You could add more app settings such as:

SENDGRID_DEV_APIKEY, SENDGRID_STAGE_APIKEY, SENDGRID_PROD_APIKEY

Then in your code check what environment the code is running and use the appropriate app setting/api key.

```
var apiKey = "";

//GetCurrentEnvironment() is a method you would write that contains logic to determine what "environment" is being used.

if (GetCurrentEnvironment() == "dev") {
  apiKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_DEV_APIKEY");
} else if (GetCurrentEnvironment() == "stage") {
  apiKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_STAGE_APIKEY");
} else if (GetCurrentEnvironment() == "prod") {
  apiKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_PROD_APIKEY");
} 

var transportWeb = new Web(apiKey);
```